# Jq trim with regex or position of char

Tags: jq

The CloudWatch log format for Aurora Postgresql delayed queries is as follows.

```json
{
    "nextForwardToken": "f/37657393414703861243420284798371757973629840396172525568/s", 
    "events": [
        {
            "ingestionTime": 1688615727267, 
            "timestamp": 1688615724000, 
            "message": "2023-07-06 03:55:24 UTC:11.11.11.11(51400):testUser@postgres:[9802]:LOG:  duration: 2004.016 ms  statement: select pg_sleep(2);"
        }, 
        {
            "ingestionTime": 1688615925270, 
            "timestamp": 1688615922000, 
            "message": "2023-07-06 03:58:42 UTC:111.22.331.41(1230):testService@postgres:[8602]:LOG:  duration: 2009.526 ms  statement: select pg_sleep(2);"
        }
    ], 
    "nextBackwardToken": "b/37657388999156311934356902534929058635511305773902397440/s"
}
```

I want to create html format using jq command.
I want to parse message field and The desired format like this:

| Time(UTC) | clientIP | user@db | Query_time(ms) | Query |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-06 03:55:24 | 11.11.11.11 | testUser@postgres | 2004.016 | select pg_sleep(2) |
| 2023-07-06 03:58:42 | 111.22.331.41 | testService@postgres | 2009.526 | select pg_sleep(2) |

To create the table, I tried various methods.

<1>
I wanted to apply the pattern to startswith and trim, but I couldn't find the material and it didn't apply.

```
/usr/local/bin/jq -r '
def to_row: "<tr>",.[],"</tr>";
def to_cell: "<td>",.,"</td>";
(
  .events[] | select(.message | contains("duration:")) | .message/"\n" | map(
    (select(startswith("\(.[0:4])-\(.[4:6])-\(.[6:8]) \(.[8:10]):\(.[10:12]):\(.[12:14])")))
  | map(@html | to_cell)
  | to_row
)
'
```

<2>
This method seems to be able to split the fields, but not in the desired direction.

```html
.events[] | .message | split(":")

<tr>
<td>
2023-07-06 03
</td>
<td>
55
</td>
<td>
24 UTC
</td>
<td>
11.11.11.11(51400)
</td>
<td>
testUser@postgres
</td>
<td>
[9802]
</td>
<td>
LOG
</td>
<td>
  duration
</td>
<td>
 2004.016 ms  statement
</td>
<td>
 select pg_sleep(2);
</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way to make it clean in the jq command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using regular expressions with [`capture`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#capture%28val%29%2Ccapture%28regex%3Bflags%29):

```bash
.events[].message | capture([
  "(?<date>[\\d-]+ [\\d:]+)",
  "(?<ip>[\\d.]+)",
  "(?<user>[^:]+)",
  "", "LOG", "duration",
  "(?<time>[\\d.]+)",
  "(?<query>.*)"
] | join("[^:]*: *"))
| [.date, .ip, .user, .time, .query | @html "<td>\(.)</td>"]
| "<tr>\(add)</tr>"
```

```html
<tr><td>2023-07-06 03:55:24</td><td>11.11.11.11</td><td>testUser@postgres</td><td>2004.016</td><td>select pg_sleep(2);</td></tr>
<tr><td>2023-07-06 03:58:42</td><td>111.22.331.41</td><td>testService@postgres</td><td>2009.526</td><td>select pg_sleep(2);</td></tr>
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/GGb1WrSIVIL)

---

To add some simple pretty-printing, you could replace the last line with

```bash
| "<tr>\n\(map("  \(.)\n") | add)</tr>"
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>2023-07-06 03:55:24</td>
  <td>11.11.11.11</td>
  <td>testUser@postgres</td>
  <td>2004.016</td>
  <td>select pg_sleep(2);</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2023-07-06 03:58:42</td>
  <td>111.22.331.41</td>
  <td>testService@postgres</td>
  <td>2009.526</td>
  <td>select pg_sleep(2);</td>
</tr>
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XRCKeXHDF_E)

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. This is the answer I want. This may be a bit silly question, but where can I learn this grammar?

Comment: @P.Lonnie If by grammar you mean purely regular expressions, there's thousands of tutorials on the Internet. [Here](https://github.com/ziishaned/learn-regex)'s one of them. Apart from that, jq's `capture` works with the `(?<key>regex)` syntax, and constructs a result object with the keys as fields. The rest is mostly just string juggling with jq: composing the final regex based on its logical parts by joining them by another regex, then, for the match results, escaping HTML special characters using `@html`, and surrounding these HTML-encoded strings with other markup strings (tags).

Comment: I will do my best by following the guide you gave me.
I'm sorry I'm not used to it yet, but I'm asking for one more help.

If a new line is included in the query, only up to the beginning of the new line is output.
Is there a way to mark this to the end?

```statement: select pg_sleep(2)\n\tas \"A\";"```
I want .. ```query : select pg_sleep(2) as "A";```

Comment: I got an answer myself.  before cpature i use gsub command. ```gsub("[\\n\\t]"; " ")```   :)

Comment: @P.Lonnie A simpler way could be to provide `capture` with the `m` flag which [stands for](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Regularexpressions) "Multi line mode (`.` will match newlines)": Change `capture([…] | join(…))` to `capture([…] | join(…); "m")`, see the [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Y6QVuFF2MXg).

Comment: thank you.
The method you described is more effective. I changed it to append m and it works great. Thank you again and have a nice day.

I hope that one day I will be able to answer others.